# CodeIgniter: View doesn't load if I use die() function

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, die

I have the following code. Checks if the user is logged in or not.
When the variable $is_logged_in is not set or is False, I load a message view.
Unfortunately, at the same time the system loads the restricted content view.
So I used die() function, and now only shows a blank page.

What can I do to only load the message view when the user is not logged in?
Thanks.

```
if(!isset($is_logged_in) OR $is_logged_in == FALSE)
{
     $data['main_content'] = 'not_logged_in';

     $data['data'] = '';

     $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

     die();
}
```

Comment: You _never_ wanna `die()` in CodeIgniter, it's a wrong approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway. I used a redirect to the login page, and a flashdata variable

```
if(!isset($is_logged_in) OR $is_logged_in == FALSE)
   {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','You must be logged in to access restricted area');
       redirect('login/');
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Actually, I've found an answer to mantain the URL and not redirect:

```php
$data['main_content'] = 'unauthorized_access';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

// Force the CI engine to render the content generated until now    
$this->CI =& get_instance(); 
$this->CI->output->_display();

die();
```

Comment: Just hit this in an AJAX controller I'm writing while doing a lot of header inspection in the constructor. +1 for digging through the output class so I don't have to :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been messing around with this for a while. If you're using `die` or `exit` after trying to load a view, CI shows a blank page.

The solution would be to use `return`, which stops execution of the current function, and does not execute anything after below that.

A simple example:

```
public function validate(){
 //validation code

 if(!$valid){
  $this->load->view('error');
  return;
 }

 //This code won't run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CI is probably using output buffering (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). If you want to load a view and kill the script, you will need to flush the buffer. This would normally be done at the very end of the script, but die()ing stops it from getting there.

```
if(!isset($is_logged_in) OR $is_logged_in == FALSE)
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'not_logged_in';
    $data['data'] = '';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

    ob_flush();
    die();
}
```

Comment: When I put ob_flush() throws:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: ob_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush.

Thanks